# Android Snake Game (How to add audio)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, audio

I'm trying to modify the Snake game code to trigger a sound for the following:

- As it moves from tile to tile
- When it eats an apple
- When it hits itself or the wall

The code I believe is the same or nearly the same that is available on GitHub. I've tried to use the MediaPlayer class to create a MediaPlayer object for each sound:

```
MediaPlayer mpOver = new MediaPlayer();
```

Then set the object to the raw file by:

```
mpOver.create(Snake.this, R.raw.bump);
```

And then triggering the sound in a method by:

```
mpOver.start();
```

However, I can only get this to work in the onCreate method in the Snake class.

As of right now I only have the one MediaPlayer object declared mpOver. Which will eventually make a sound when the snake moves from tile to tile. The reason I have it in the the Snake class in the onCreate method is just to test if I could get it to make a sound, which it does when it launches.I just don't know how to get it to the rest of the app. Can anyone provide any advice?

The updated code for the Snake class is below:

Thanks for the help, however, I'm still having problems. I used you code and it runs fine with no audio, until I add

```
MediaPlayer mpOver = activity.getMpOver();
mpOver.start();
```

The app just crashes, when the method is called that is supposed to play the sound.

I get this error in the android monitor:

> 02-15 09:25:51.576 4163-4163/com.example.android.snake E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                            Process: com.example.android.snake, PID: 4163
>                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                at com.example.android.snake.SnakeView.updateSnake(SnakeView.java:501)
>                                                                                at com.example.android.snake.SnakeView.update(SnakeView.java:427)
>                                                                                at com.example.android.snake.SnakeView$RefreshHandler.handleMessage(SnakeView.java:131)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Sorry, my update code is below... and thanks soo much for the help.

```
package com.example.android.snake;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

 /**
 * SnakeView: implementation of a simple game of Snake
 * 
 * 
 */


public class SnakeView extends TileView {



private static final String TAG = "SnakeView";

private Snake activity;

public void setActivity(Snake activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}


/**
 * Current mode of application: READY to run, RUNNING, or you have already
 * lost. static final ints are used instead of an enum for performance
 * reasons.
 */
private int mMode = READY;
public static final int PAUSE = 0;
public static final int READY = 1;
public static final int RUNNING = 2;
public static final int LOSE = 3;

/**
 * Current direction the snake is headed.
 */
private int mDirection = NORTH;
private int mNextDirection = NORTH;
private static final int NORTH = 1;
private static final int SOUTH = 2;
private static final int EAST = 3;
private static final int WEST = 4;

/**
 * Labels for the drawables that will be loaded into the TileView class
 */
private static final int RED_STAR = 1;
private static final int YELLOW_STAR = 2;
private static final int GREEN_STAR = 3;

/**
 * mScore: used to track the number of apples captured mMoveDelay: number of
 * milliseconds between snake movements. This will decrease as apples are
 * captured.
 */
private long mScore = 0;
private long mMoveDelay = 600;
/**
 * mLastMove: tracks the absolute time when the snake last moved, and is used
 * to determine if a move should be made based on mMoveDelay.
 */
private long mLastMove;

/**
 * mStatusText: text shows to the user in some run states
 */
private TextView mStatusText;

/**
 * mSnakeTrail: a list of Coordinates that make up the snake's body
 * mAppleList: the secret location of the juicy apples the snake craves.
 */
private ArrayList<Coordinate> mSnakeTrail = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
private ArrayList<Coordinate> mAppleList = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();

/**
 * Everyone needs a little randomness in their life
 */
private static final Random RNG = new Random();

/**
 * Create a simple handler that we can use to cause animation to happen.  We
 * set ourselves as a target and we can use the sleep()
 * function to cause an update/invalidate to occur at a later date.
 */
private RefreshHandler mRedrawHandler = new RefreshHandler();

class RefreshHandler extends Handler {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        SnakeView.this.update();
        SnakeView.this.invalidate();

    }

    public void sleep(long delayMillis) {
        this.removeMessages(0);
        sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);
    }
   };


/**
 * Constructs a SnakeView based on inflation from XML
 * 
 * @param context
 * @param attrs
 */
public SnakeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initSnakeView();


 }

public SnakeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initSnakeView();
 }

private void initSnakeView() {
    setFocusable(true);

    Resources r = this.getContext().getResources();

    resetTiles(4);
    loadTile(RED_STAR, r.getDrawable(R.drawable.redstar));
    loadTile(YELLOW_STAR, r.getDrawable(R.drawable.yellowstar));
    loadTile(GREEN_STAR, r.getDrawable(R.drawable.greenstar));

  }


private void initNewGame() {
    mSnakeTrail.clear();
    mAppleList.clear();


    // For now we're just going to load up a short default eastbound snake
    // that's just turned north


    mSnakeTrail.add(new Coordinate(7, 7));
    mSnakeTrail.add(new Coordinate(6, 7));
    mSnakeTrail.add(new Coordinate(5, 7));
    mSnakeTrail.add(new Coordinate(4, 7));
    mSnakeTrail.add(new Coordinate(3, 7));
    mSnakeTrail.add(new Coordinate(2, 7));
    mNextDirection = NORTH;

    // Two apples to start with
    addRandomApple();
    addRandomApple();

    mMoveDelay = 600;
    mScore = 0;
}


/**
 * Given a ArrayList of coordinates, we need to flatten them into an array of
 * ints before we can stuff them into a map for flattening and storage.
 * 
 * @param cvec : a ArrayList of Coordinate objects
 * @return : a simple array containing the x/y values of the coordinates
 * as [x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3...]
 */
private int[] coordArrayListToArray(ArrayList<Coordinate> cvec) {
    int count = cvec.size();
    int[] rawArray = new int[count * 2];
    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
        Coordinate c = cvec.get(index);
        rawArray[2 * index] = c.x;
        rawArray[2 * index + 1] = c.y;
    }
    return rawArray;
}

/**
 * Save game state so that the user does not lose anything
 * if the game process is killed while we are in the 
 * background.
 * 
 * @return a Bundle with this view's state
 */
public Bundle saveState() {
    Bundle map = new Bundle();

    map.putIntArray("mAppleList", coordArrayListToArray(mAppleList));
    map.putInt("mDirection", Integer.valueOf(mDirection));
    map.putInt("mNextDirection", Integer.valueOf(mNextDirection));
    map.putLong("mMoveDelay", Long.valueOf(mMoveDelay));
    map.putLong("mScore", Long.valueOf(mScore));
    map.putIntArray("mSnakeTrail", coordArrayListToArray(mSnakeTrail));

    return map;
}

/**
 * Given a flattened array of ordinate pairs, we reconstitute them into a
 * ArrayList of Coordinate objects
 * 
 * @param rawArray : [x1,y1,x2,y2,...]
 * @return a ArrayList of Coordinates
 */
private ArrayList<Coordinate> coordArrayToArrayList(int[] rawArray) {
    ArrayList<Coordinate> coordArrayList = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();

    int coordCount = rawArray.length;
    for (int index = 0; index < coordCount; index += 2) {
        Coordinate c = new Coordinate(rawArray[index], rawArray[index + 1]);
        coordArrayList.add(c);
    }
    return coordArrayList;
}

/**
 * Restore game state if our process is being relaunched
 * 
 * @param icicle a Bundle containing the game state
 */
public void restoreState(Bundle icicle) {
    setMode(PAUSE);

    mAppleList = coordArrayToArrayList(icicle.getIntArray("mAppleList"));
    mDirection = icicle.getInt("mDirection");
    mNextDirection = icicle.getInt("mNextDirection");
    mMoveDelay = icicle.getLong("mMoveDelay");
    mScore = icicle.getLong("mScore");
    mSnakeTrail = coordArrayToArrayList(icicle.getIntArray("mSnakeTrail"));
}

/*
 * handles key events in the game. Update the direction our snake is traveling
 * based on the DPAD. Ignore events that would cause the snake to immediately
 * turn back on itself.
 * 
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.view.View#onKeyDown(int, android.os.KeyEvent)
 */
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP) {
        if (mMode == READY | mMode == LOSE) {
            /*
             * At the beginning of the game, or the end of a previous one,
             * we should start a new game.
             */
            initNewGame();
            setMode(RUNNING);
            update();
            return (true);
        }

        if (mMode == PAUSE) {
            /*
             * If the game is merely paused, we should just continue where
             * we left off.
             */
            setMode(RUNNING);
            update();
            return (true);
        }

        if (mDirection != SOUTH) {
            mNextDirection = NORTH;
        }
        return (true);
    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) {
        if (mDirection != NORTH) {
            mNextDirection = SOUTH;
        }
        return (true);
    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT) {
        if (mDirection != EAST) {
            mNextDirection = WEST;
        }
        return (true);
    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT) {
        if (mDirection != WEST) {
            mNextDirection = EAST;
        }
        return (true);
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, msg);
}

/**
 * Sets the TextView that will be used to give information (such as "Game
 * Over" to the user.
 * 
 * @param newView
 */
public void setTextView(TextView newView) {
    mStatusText = newView;
}

/**
 * Updates the current mode of the application (RUNNING or PAUSED or the like)
 * as well as sets the visibility of textview for notification
 * 
 * @param newMode
 */
public void setMode(int newMode) {
    int oldMode = mMode;
    mMode = newMode;

    if (newMode == RUNNING & oldMode != RUNNING) {
        mStatusText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        update();
        return;
    }

    Resources res = getContext().getResources();
    CharSequence str = "";
    if (newMode == PAUSE) {
        str = res.getText(R.string.mode_pause);
    }
    if (newMode == READY) {
        str = res.getText(R.string.mode_ready);
    }
    if (newMode == LOSE) {
        str = res.getString(R.string.mode_lose_prefix) + mScore
              + res.getString(R.string.mode_lose_suffix);
    }

    mStatusText.setText(str);
    mStatusText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

/**
 * Selects a random location within the garden that is not currently covered
 * by the snake. Currently _could_ go into an infinite loop if the snake
 * currently fills the garden, but we'll leave discovery of this prize to a
 * truly excellent snake-player.
 * 
 */
private void addRandomApple() {
    Coordinate newCoord = null;
    boolean found = false;
    while (!found) {
        // Choose a new location for our apple
        int newX = 1 + RNG.nextInt(mXTileCount - 2);
        int newY = 1 + RNG.nextInt(mYTileCount - 2);
        newCoord = new Coordinate(newX, newY);

        // Make sure it's not already under the snake
        boolean collision = false;
        int snakelength = mSnakeTrail.size();
        for (int index = 0; index < snakelength; index++) {
            if (mSnakeTrail.get(index).equals(newCoord)) {
                collision = true;
            }
        }
        // if we're here and there's been no collision, then we have
        // a good location for an apple. Otherwise, we'll circle back
        // and try again
        found = !collision;
    }
    if (newCoord == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Somehow ended up with a null newCoord!");
    }
    mAppleList.add(newCoord);
}

/**
 * Handles the basic update loop, checking to see if we are in the running
 * state, determining if a move should be made, updating the snake's location.
 */
public void update() {
    if (mMode == RUNNING) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (now - mLastMove > mMoveDelay) {
            clearTiles();
            updateWalls();
            updateSnake();
            updateApples();
            mLastMove = now;
        }
        mRedrawHandler.sleep(mMoveDelay);
    }

}

/**
 * Draws some walls.
 * 
 */
private void updateWalls() {
    for (int x = 0; x < mXTileCount; x++) {
        setTile(GREEN_STAR, x, 0);
        setTile(GREEN_STAR, x, mYTileCount - 1);
    }
    for (int y = 1; y < mYTileCount - 1; y++) {
        setTile(GREEN_STAR, 0, y);
        setTile(GREEN_STAR, mXTileCount - 1, y);
    }
}

/**
 * Draws some apples.
 * 
 */
private void updateApples() {
    for (Coordinate c : mAppleList) {
        setTile(YELLOW_STAR, c.x, c.y);
    }
}

/**
 * Figure out which way the snake is going, see if he's run into anything (the
 * walls, himself, or an apple). If he's not going to die, we then add to the
 * front and subtract from the rear in order to simulate motion. If we want to
 * grow him, we don't subtract from the rear.
 * 
 */

private void updateSnake() {
    boolean growSnake = false;

    // grab the snake by the head
    Coordinate head = mSnakeTrail.get(0);
    Coordinate newHead = new Coordinate(1, 1);

    mDirection = mNextDirection;

    switch (mDirection) {
    case EAST: {
        newHead = new Coordinate(head.x + 1, head.y);
        break;
    }
    case WEST: {
        newHead = new Coordinate(head.x - 1, head.y);
        break;
    }
    case NORTH: {
        newHead = new Coordinate(head.x, head.y - 1);
        break;
    }
    case SOUTH: {
        newHead = new Coordinate(head.x, head.y + 1);
        break;
    }
    }

    // Collision detection
    // For now we have a 1-square wall around the entire arena
    if ((newHead.x < 1) || (newHead.y < 1) || (newHead.x > mXTileCount - 2)
            || (newHead.y > mYTileCount - 2)) {
        MediaPlayer mpOver = activity.getMpOver();
        mpOver.start();
        setMode(LOSE);




        return;

    }

    // Look for collisions with itself
    int snakelength = mSnakeTrail.size();
    for (int snakeindex = 0; snakeindex < snakelength; snakeindex++) {
        Coordinate c = mSnakeTrail.get(snakeindex);
        if (c.equals(newHead)) {
            setMode(LOSE);
            //mpOver.start();
            return;
        }
    }

    // Look for apples
    int applecount = mAppleList.size();
    for (int appleindex = 0; appleindex < applecount; appleindex++) {
        Coordinate c = mAppleList.get(appleindex);
        if (c.equals(newHead)) {
            mAppleList.remove(c);
            addRandomApple();

            mScore++;
            mMoveDelay *= 0.9;

            growSnake = true;
        }
    }

    // push a new head onto the ArrayList and pull off the tail
    mSnakeTrail.add(0, newHead);
    // except if we want the snake to grow
    if (!growSnake) {
        mSnakeTrail.remove(mSnakeTrail.size() - 1);
    }

    int index = 0;
    for (Coordinate c : mSnakeTrail) {
        if (index == 0) {
            setTile(YELLOW_STAR, c.x, c.y);
        } else {
            setTile(RED_STAR, c.x, c.y);
        }
        index++;
    }

}

/**
 * Simple class containing two integer values and a comparison function.
 * There's probably something I should use instead, but this was quick and
 * easy to build.
 * 
 */
private class Coordinate {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Coordinate(int newX, int newY) {
        x = newX;
        y = newY;
    }

    public boolean equals(Coordinate other) {
        if (x == other.x && y == other.y) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Coordinate: [" + x + "," + y + "]";
    }
}

}
```

The Snake view code is below:

```
public class Snake extends Activity {

private SnakeView mSnakeView;


private static String ICICLE_KEY = "snake-view";

MediaPlayer mpOver;

public MediaPlayer getMpOver() {

    return mpOver;
}

/**
 * Called when Activity is first created. Turns off the title bar, sets up
 * the content views, and fires up the SnakeView.
 * 
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.snake_layout);
    mpOver.create(Snake.this, R.raw.bump);


    mSnakeView = (SnakeView) findViewById(R.id.snake);
    mSnakeView.setTextView((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text));
    mSnakeView.setActivity(this);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // We were just launched -- set up a new game
        mSnakeView.setMode(SnakeView.READY);
    } else {
        // We are being restored
        Bundle map = savedInstanceState.getBundle(ICICLE_KEY);
        if (map != null) {
            mSnakeView.restoreState(map);
        } else {
            mSnakeView.setMode(SnakeView.PAUSE);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Pause the game along with the activity
    mSnakeView.setMode(SnakeView.PAUSE);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //Store the game state
    outState.putBundle(ICICLE_KEY, mSnakeView.saveState());
}



}
```

We are getting somewhere now... It doesn't crash but doesn't play the audio either. This is what I'm seeing in the Android monitor.

> 02-15 10:18:13.409 17511-17511/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
>   02-15 10:18:13.478 17511-17511/com.example.android.snake W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.android.snake-1/lib/x86
>   02-15 10:18:13.486 17511-17511/com.example.android.snake I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.android.snake, real application class is null.
>   02-15 10:18:13.671 17511-17511/com.example.android.snake W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.android.snake-1/lib/x86
>   02-15 10:18:13.787 17511-17511/com.example.android.snake D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
>   02-15 10:18:18.037 17511-17511/com.example.android.snake D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
>   02-15 10:18:28.095 17511-17511/com.example.android.snake E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 1
>   02-15 10:18:28.095 17511-17511/com.example.android.snake E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
>   02-15 10:18:28.096 17511-17511/com.example.android.snake E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)

I've add the 
     activity.startMpOver();
and it wanted me to add the below method to the Snake view. I added it, and nothing changed. So I added the mpOver.start() to the methods. Still no go.

```
public void startMpOver() {
    mpOver.start();
}
```

I'm still getting this

02-15 11:11:56.049 23934-23934/com.example.android.snake E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 1
02-15 11:11:56.049 23934-23934/com.example.android.snake E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
02-15 11:11:56.057 23934-23934/com.example.android.snake E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
02-15 11:12:17.878 23934-23934/com.example.android.snake E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 0
02-15 11:12:43.165 23934-23934/com.example.android.snake E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 0
02-15 11:12:52.872 23934-23934/com.example.android.snake E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your Snake activity class to this:

```
public class Snake extends Activity {

    private SnakeView mSnakeView;

    private static String ICICLE_KEY = "snake-view";

    MediaPlayer mpOver; 
    boolean mpOverPrepared = false;

    public MediaPlayer getMpOver() {

        return mpOver;
    }

    /**
     * Called when Activity is first created. Turns off the title bar, sets up
     * the content views, and fires up the SnakeView.
     *
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.snake_layout);
        mpOver = new MediaPlayer();
        mpOver.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mpOverPrepared = true;
            }
        });
        mpOver.create(Snake.this, R.raw.bump);


        mSnakeView = (SnakeView) findViewById(R.id.snake);
        mSnakeView.setTextView((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text));
        mSnakeView.setActivity(this);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // We were just launched -- set up a new game
            mSnakeView.setMode(SnakeView.READY);
        } else {
            // We are being restored
            Bundle map = savedInstanceState.getBundle(ICICLE_KEY);
            if (map != null) {
                mSnakeView.restoreState(map);
            } else {
                mSnakeView.setMode(SnakeView.PAUSE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Pause the game along with the activity
        mSnakeView.setMode(SnakeView.PAUSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        //Store the game state
        outState.putBundle(ICICLE_KEY, mSnakeView.saveState());
    }

    public void startMpOver() {
        if(mpOverPrepared) {
            mpOver.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you want to play the mpOver in your SnakeView you do this

```
activity.startMpOver();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, I'm still having problems. I used you code and it runs fine with no audio, until I add 

    MediaPlayer mpOver = activity.getMpOver();
    mpOver.start();

The app just crashes, when the method is called that is supposed to play the sound.

Comment: Please see my edited main post to see the Android monitor error.

Comment: activity.getMpOver(); returns null. You have to fix this. I cant help you if you dont post the edited code

Comment: I've added the updated code. I had to delete the original code because of character limits. Thanks so much for you advice and help.

Comment: Alright, I added that, now it doesn't crash, but plays no audio. Please see the Android monitor in the edited post.

Comment: error state 1 is because data has not been loaded when you call start(). Check the edited answer

Comment: Another update to the post... I appreciate your help. But I feel like I'm just not going to get this.

Comment: check if the file related to R.raw.bump is an audio file and is a format that Android can decode. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html

Comment: It should be fine. It's a wav file, and I've tested it by calling the start method in onCreate and it plays the tone when the app launches.
mpOver.create(Snake.this, R.raw.die).start(); plays the tone in onCreate in the Snake view.

Comment: Thanks so much, I finally got it working. Your a life saver.

Comment: @scsims Please accept my answer if It helped you. Good coding anyway